# Adding path to remote_api_shell.py automatically

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I use `remote_api_shell.py` frequently, and I'd like to automate adding the path to my vendored libraries.  This is what I currently do:

1. `cat appengine_config.py`  This outputs:

> ```
> from google.appengine.ext import vendor
> vendor.add('lib')
> ```

2. `python ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py myapp`
3. Copy and paste the output of 1 into the shell.

Is there a way to start `remote_api_shell.py` and have it automatically include vendored libs?

Further, is there to execute a Python script that will be in the environment of `remote_api_shell.py`?  I want to do some data processing locally that needs to be within the GAE sandbox.

Comment: Try `python -m appengine_config.py ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py myapp`

Comment: I get the error `Import by filename is not supported` (after adding the path to `appengine_congif.py`).  I'm in a virtualenv in case that makes a difference...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was shooting for - same as for running w/ `pdb`, but if it's not supported it's a miss. FWIW I'm on linux, without a venv (but I don't think the venv matters).